# I'm getting this error when try to update to php5

Tags: apt, apache2, dpkg, php

When I try to upgrade php from 5.3 to 5.6, this wild error appears

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 98172 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2-bin (from .../apache2-bin_2.4.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3_amd64.deb) ...
**dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/apache2', which is also in package apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)**
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using [PPA for PHP 5.6](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6) for Ubuntu 12.04 (precise).

Your issue is because that `apache2-mpm-prefork` is already obsoleted in 2.4.x.  You just need to remove `apache2-mpm-prefork`, then install `apache2`, and default is prefork mode.